Differences between `%Cpu(s)` in summary area and `%CPU` in task area in `top` command
I have got a question after I've read top.1 man page. Does %Cpu(s) and %CPU the same thing except one for overview usage and one for task-specified usage? And How to calculate those two.
Quote from SUMMARY DISPLAY which relates to %Cpu(s)

2b. TASK and CPU States
...
Line 2 shows CPU state percentages based on the interval since the last refresh.
...

Quote from FIELDS/Columns which relates to %CPU

%CPU  --  CPU Usage
The task's share of the elapsed CPU time since the last screen update, expressed as a percentage of total CPU time.
...

Could I derive formulas below from it? When Irix mode is on and thread mode is off which are the default settings.
CPU% is equal to the sum of one task's us, sy, ni, wa, hi, si, st since the last delay divided by delay time. The EBNF would be
CPU% = sum(one task's us,sy,ni,wa,hi,si,st) since the last delay / delay time

Cpu(s)% is equal to the sum of all tasks' us or sy or ni or id or wa or hi or si or st since the last delay divided by delay time. The EBNF would be
Cpu(s)% = sum(all tasks' (us | sy | ni | id | wa | hi | si | st)) since the last delay  / delay time

Or Cpu(s)% is equal to the sum of all tasks' us or sy or ni or id or wa or hi or si or st since the last delay divided by delay time multiply the number of cores. The EBNF would be
Cpu(s)% = sum(all tasks' (us | sy | ni | id | wa | hi | si | st)) since the last delay  / (delay time * number of cores)

And do the thread mode and Irix mode impact the Cpu(s)% or not? If so when the thread mode is off Cpu(s)% could be greater than 100 as the CPU%?
Many thanks for considering my request.
